# React -enzyme Testing form based on useSelector and hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a form and check if dispatch to redux has been fired 
i am sharing here the component and the test.(could not manage to run it on the sandbox)

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-frog-y4n4y?file=/src/test.ts

so in that test, I did not manage to click on a button(type submit) and change the disabled type (I manage to update the values)

how can I test the form in an easy way  and how can I check my login action from redux has been fired

my test:

```
  it.only('should click on the button  ', async () => {
    const useSelectorSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
    const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch');
    useDispatchSpy.mockImplementation(() => (cb: any) => cb);
    useSelectorSpy.mockReturnValue({
      authenticated: false,
      isLoading: false,
      authError: false
    });
    const wrapper = mountWithIntl(<Login />);
    let usernameTextFiled = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'username-textfield').first();
    let passwordTextfiled = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'password-textfield').first();

    act(() => {
      usernameTextFiled.props().onChange?.({
        currentTarget: {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
          // @ts-ignore
          value: 'ttt'
        }
      });
      passwordTextfiled.props().onChange?.({
        currentTarget: {
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore
          // @ts-ignore
          value: 'password'
        }
      });
    });

    wrapper.update();
    usernameTextFiled = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'username-textfield').first();
    let loginButton = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'submit-button').first();

     // this is work
     expect(loginButton.prop('disabled')).toEqual(false);

    const form = wrapper.find('form').at(0);
    await submitForm(form ,loginButton);
    loginButton = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'submit-button').first();
    wrapper.update();
    loginButton = findComponentByProperty(wrapper, 'submit-button').first();

     expect(loginButton.prop('disabled')).toBe(true);
```

formm submitter

```
export const submitForm = async (nativeFormWrapper: any, button) => {
  await act(async () => {
    nativeFormWrapper.simulate('submit', { preventDefault: () => {} });

    button.props().onSubmit?.({
        preventDefault: () => {}
    });
  });
};
```